# Exception when attempting to download price historical data with forexconnect in python

Tags: python, download, price, forex

I am trying to download historical price data using forexconnect (can be installed with `pip install forexconnect`) and Python.  I have been doing this successfully always but all of a sudden my attempts return an error message which I can not explain. My internet connection is over Fiber and works without any problems.

I was advised by the support team of the forexconnect API to use a specific web address to install forexconnect.

So I proceeded as follows:

**Uninstalled the previous version**

```
(base) C:\Users\user>pip uninstall forexconnect
Found existing installation: forexconnect 1.6.41
Uninstalling forexconnect-1.6.41:
Would remove:
c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\forexconnect-1.6.41.dist-info\*
c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\forexconnect\*
Proceed (y/n)? y
Successfully uninstalled forexconnect-1.6.41
```

**Installed forexconnect using the pip command found in the website I was pointed to (https://test.pypi.org/project/forexconnect/#files):**

```
(base) C:\Users\user>pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ forexconnect
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting forexconnect
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/40/978d5b11e3b144bf77023f624cf607d4fc35b5caaa369fe484bab4ab0765/forexconnect-1.6.41-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (5.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.9 MB 1.3 MB/s
Installing collected packages: forexconnect
Successfully installed forexconnect-1.6.41
```

**Verified the installation of the forexconnect:**

```
pip show forexconnect

Name: forexconnect
Version: 1.6.41
Summary: ForexConnect API is a trading API for the FXCM Group: https://www.fxcm.com/uk/
Home-page: https://github.com/gehtsoft/forex-connect
Author: Gehtsoft USA, LLC
Author-email: contact@gehtsoftusa.com
License: Other/Proprietary License
Location: c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: 
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

**Run the code to download historical price data:**

```
import forexconnect
 
import pandas as pd
 
pair_string = 'USD/CNH'
 
time_interval_string = 'm30'
 
start_date = pd.Timestamp('1990-01-01')
 
from forexconnect import fxcorepy, ForexConnect
 
def session_status_changed(session: fxcorepy.O2GSession,   status: fxcorepy.AO2GSessionStatus.O2GSessionStatus):
    print("Trading session status: " + str(status))
 
with ForexConnect() as fx:
 
    try:

        fx.login("D261296694", "Oop5f", "fxcorporate.com/Hosts.jsp",
                 "Demo", session_status_callback=session_status_changed)

        history = fx.get_history(pair_string, time_interval_string, start_date)

        fx_df = pd.DataFrame(history)

        fx_df['Ticker'] = pair_string

    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: " + str(e))

    try:
        fx.logout()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: " + str(e))
```

**Received the following error message as before:**

```
Trading session status: CONNECTING
Trading session status: CONNECTED
Exception: QuotesManager error: HTTP request failed object='/pricearchive/catalog.xml' errorCode=52 code: QuotesServerConnectionError subcode: 52
Trading session status: DISCONNECTING
Trading session status: DISCONNECTED
```

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace please?

Comment: The stacktrace returned by python has been provided above.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should work properly:

```
import datetime as dt

pair_string = 'USD/CNH'

time_interval_string = 'M30'

start_date = dt.datetime.strptime("MM.DD.YYYY HH:MM:SS", '%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
end_date = dt.datetime.strptime("MM.DD.YYYY HH:MM:SS", '%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

with ForexConnect() as fx:
 
    try:

        fx.login("D261296694", "Oop5f", "fxcorporate.com/Hosts.jsp",
                 "Demo", session_status_callback=session_status_changed)

        history = fx.get_history(pair_string, time_interval_string, start_date, end_date)

        fx_df = pd.DataFrame(history)

        fx_df['Ticker'] = pair_string

    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: " + str(e))
```

Note the dates has to be set properly by replacing `"MM.DD.YYYY HH:MM:SS"` with desired date. Eg `"1.1.1990 00:00:00"`

Full example [here](https://fxcodebase.com/bin/forexconnect/1.6.0/python/web-content.html#get_history_py.html)

Comment: I run your code and returns the same error message:  Exception: QuotesManager error: HTTP request failed object='/pricearchive/catalog.xml' errorCode=52 code: QuotesServerConnectionError subcode: 52